# Can't run any container with an entrypoint script

Tags: docker

I work with docker on a daily basis, but this morning, when I tried to launch some containers, it failed for every of my containers with an entrypoint script:

```
$ docker run postgres:11
bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied

$ docker run mysql:5
/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied

$ docker run php:7.3-apache
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /usr/local/bin/docker-php-entrypoint
```

I managed to `docker run hello-world` without errors.

What happens? I don't think I have changed anything important on my computer since the last time it worked... I am on Ubuntu 20.04. 
Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

I still don't know what was going on. I managed to make it work again by removing `docker-ce` and re-installing it:

```
sudo apt-get remove docker-ce
sudo apt install docker-ce
docker run postgres:11
  ==> ok, worked!
```

But, each time I shut down my laptop and then turn it on, I have the same problem again, docker doesn't run any container with an entrypoint.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `docker run postgres:11 /bin/sh` and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, following the idea of @PieterBeyens, I checked apparmor, and indeed,it was denying me read access to `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh`. It also appeared that I had a mixed snap/apt installation of docker and docker-compose. It was a mess.

So, for future readers, what I did and finally worked (you may need to adapt, but you have the general idea):

```
# Remove the docker and docker-compose snaps
sudo snap remove docker-compose 
sudo snap remove docker
# Remove the packages via apt
sudo apt-get purge -y  docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
# Remove the apparmor profiles (snap ones for docker)
sudo aa-remove-unknown
# Reinstall via apt
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic docker-ce-cli=5:19.03.8~3-0~ubuntu-bionic containerd.io
```

And I also [resinstalled `docker-compose` via curl](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

Answer (score 1):

Apparmor might be the cause. You can find out by running dmesg and grep for DENIED.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. `dmesg |grep DENIED` shows, indeed, messages concerning docker: 
`[  320.601611] audit: type=1400 audit(1590564822.436:4660): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh" pid=14128 comm="bash" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[  321.386279] audit: type=1400 audit(1590564823.220:4661): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="snap.docker.dockerd" name="/bin/kmod" pid=14302 comm="exe" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=0 ouid=0`
Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: I have no experience with apparmor, I simply disabled it by following the first 3 steps in this guide: https://www.simplified.guide/ubuntu/remove-apparmor. After those steps, a reboot seemed to be necessary as well.

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 19.04 and docker installed via snap few hours ago. Apparmor was the cause, we follow the solution from the previous answer. Disable apparmor, remove apparmor which also remove snap and also remove docker. Then I installed docker via apt and works. The odd is apparmor and snap are related some how, but apparmor blocks docker which was installed via snap.