# Using Docker with Python shows an error loading libpython3.8.so.1.0

Tags: python, linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I was working on a Flask project of mine and when I booted my PC the next day it wouldn't run anymore. I tried reinstalling Docker and even reinstalling my OS (Ubuntu) and this error still shows up even with a basic example Hello World Python project. Here is the output from trying to build a simple Hello World project:

```
# docker build -t hello-world .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.8
 ---> 659f826fabf4
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5e381e0b49f2
Step 3/6 : COPY requirements.txt ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4d46722cff64
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 305e14db0fa2
/usr/local/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

run.py

```
print("Hello World")
```

And the requirements.txt is empty. It was working yesterday and I've been really struggling to figure out why it's not working now.

Comment: Please share the requirements.txt as well

Comment: it's empty for this example

Comment: How did you install Python 3.8, and how did you install Docker ?

Comment: I used snap to install Docker on Ubuntu and from my understanding Docker installs Python 3.8 (specified in Dockerfile) through docker build.

Comment: I've seen some other complaints about snap-installed Docker not working well, though more with "permission denied" type errors (_e.g._, [Can't run any container with an entrypoint script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61951453/10008173), [Permission denied as root in docker containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61982114/10008173)).  Does reinstalling Docker with APT instead of snap improve things?

Comment: It seems that using apt instead of snap has indeed fixed the problem, thank you.

Comment: You could add an answer with the fix, as this seems to be an issue faced by others.

Answer (score 2):

Using apt instead of snap for installing Docker fixed it for me.